# how to use 'Slovak alphabet ' python plot xlabel Jyputer Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, alphabetical

Is there actually a chance to use **slovak** characters like `ščžáéý`
in python plot using `matplotlib` within `xlabel`, `ylabel` etc.

```
plt.xlabel("čas")
plt.ylabel("predikované hodnoty")
```

Comment: I have spent way to much time to solve this problem so I gave this up like months ago, then I figured maybe someone can help. You can believe me that I tried many options. Non of them worked.

Comment: Apologies - the problem is that I **can** use those characters in matplotlib titles, labels etc. What version of matplotlib are you using? I'm using 1.5.2 and it works fine. Are you using python2 or python3? if you're using python2 you'll have to specify that it's a unicode string by prefixing the string with u (.e.g u"čas"). For proof that it works fine, play around on https://tmpnb.org/ as it works for me on there too

Comment: Thnak you so much, I am using *Andaconda python 2.7* at Windows machine in version. It just works with `plt.xlabel(u'čas')` as you suggested. It is awesome. You have no idea how many hours I killed to figured that out. Perhaps I had a problem to achieve so because I was using python 2.7 at *Centos 6.x server*. Much appreciate your help!!!

If there is a chance I will endorse you profile if possible. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following:
using (*Python 2.7.12 Anaconda custom (64-bit)*, *matplotlib 1.5.3*)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
Fs = 8000
f = 5
sample = 8000
x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
plt.figure(20)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel(u'čas')
plt.ylabel(u'prijatý optický výkon')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Found another problem, the solution we thought it the final and correct seems not to be right.
Considering the word like"  `u'Viditečnosť [m]'`, doen not work at all,
however `'výkon '` workd just fine.

Any idea??